# nodejs req.files con express y fileuploads me retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, nodejs, express

estoy trabajando con una web en nodejs con express y express-fileupload, pero el código para leer los archivos que me vienen del frontend desde un input type file, pero siempre me llega como undefined, este es mi código del servidor:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const hbs = require("hbs");
const path = require("path");
const sql = require("mssql");
const { config } = require("../db/db");
const session = require("express-session");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const { login } = require('./functions/login');
const { URladministrador } = require('./functions/login');



app.use(fileUpload());

app.use(
    session({
        secret: "canalParamo-Pasa.123",
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
    })
);

hbs.registerPartials(path.join(__dirname, "../", "/views/partials"));

app.post("/nuevaActa", login, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file); // return: undefined
    console.log(req.files); // return: null
});

module.exports = app
```

este es mi formulario del que mando los datos, si pongo el req.body si que me retorna los datos de los input type text, pero los type file no me pasa ningún valor, aquí os lo dejo:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-upload">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fas fa-upload"> </i> Añadir documento</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form id="formNuevaActa" action="/nuevaActa" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Título</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control tituloActa" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Introduzca título"
                name="titulo">
            </div>
          
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Tipo documento</label>
              <select class="custom-select" name="tipoDocumento" id="tipoDocumento" required>
                <option hidden>Seleccione tipo</option>
                 
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputFile">Archivo</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="file" required max-size="2000" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" class="custom-file-input"
                    id="exampleInputFile" name="acta">
                  <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Seleccione archivo</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span class="text-muted">Tamaño máximo de archivo 2MB</span>
              <br>
              <span class="text-muted">Formatos de archivo aceptados .pdf, .doc y .docx</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cancelarNuevoActa" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success subirActa" data-dismiss="modal">Subir documento</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

y este es el js por el que realizo la llama ajax al servidor para pasarle los archivos:

```
 $('#formNuevaActa').submit(function() {
        let datasend = new FormData($("#formNuevaActa")[0]);
        let nuevaActa = async() => {
            await $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/nuevaActa',
                data: datasend,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    if (res == 1) {
                        alert('El acta se ha creado con éxito');
                        location.href = "";
                        return 1;
                    } else if (res == 0) {
                        alert('Ha ocurrido un error, inténta subir el acta de nuevo mas tarde');
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        nuevaActa().then(acta => {
            console.log(acta);
            return false;
        }).catch(e => console.log('error al crear el acta', e));
        return false;
    });
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error? Muchas gracias de verdad.

Comment: dentro del objeto de req van así req.files.nombreDelInput

Comment: si, pero me sale vacio

Answer (score 0):

no he utilizado `express-fileupload`, pero no debe ser muy diferente a otros, tales como `formidable`.

Para descartar cualquier otra situación te invito a simplificar el código e ir a probar sólo lo necesario, basandome en el ejemplo obtenido [acá](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp), mi resultado es:

[image: Resultado]

Intenta utilizar este librería:

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'C:/Developer/test/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```